# Elementor Dynamiс Gallery issue

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm using Elementor module called Dynamic Gallery for showing my posts. At the top of it I have filters with tags. The question is how can I integrate the tags inside the post body in this dynamic post grid? Screenshot - http://prntscr.com/w7ykau

I've serched through all web, tried to find some php view template inside the Elementor but still no luck. Will be glad for any help from you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Pease can you add more details of what you have tried?

Comment: Thanks for replying, sure. I've been looking for an additional Elementor module that could insert post tags inside post body in gallery grid. Tried to find this post dynamic gallery template inside the Elementor core in /plugins so as to insert the tags (as I would do in some php template). But I couldn't find any solution for inserting these tags. Only filters at the top of the gallery and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using additional plugin for Elementor - https://powerpackelements.com/

It provides a special module called Advanced Posts with help of which I can insert tags in the post body as seen here - https://clip2net.com/s/4am4VND